# emacs sort files in completions buffer when opening a file

Tags: emacs

While opening a file in emacs using tab completion, emacs brings up the *Completions* buffer with a list of the possible completions. The list is ordered alphabetically. How would I configure emacs so that the default behavior is to sort the possible file completions based on time showing the newest or oldest file / directory at the top of the list? Could I further change the sorting criteria dynamically while looking at the completions buffer?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can easily [control sorting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates).

   And you can easily change sort orders on the fly.

   And for file-name completion the default sort orders include the order you are requesting. You can choose it to be your default sort order for file-name completion. Or you can choose it during file-name completion, by either cycling or completing its name.

   And you can easily define your own sort orders.
2. If you use only *vanilla* Emacs then you can fiddle with completion metadata for file-name completion. See metadata categories `display-sort-function` and `cycle-sort-function`.

   For example, you can define your own completion command that acts similar to `read-file-name` but that uses a different sort function.

   This is what vanilla library `tmm.el` does, for example:

```el
    (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
       #'tmm-add-prompt
       (completing-read
          (concat gl-str " (up/down to change, PgUp to menu): ")
          (tmm--completion-table tmm-km-list) nil t nil
          (cons 'tmm--history (- (* 2 history-len) index-of-default))))

     (defun tmm--completion-table (items)
       (lambda (string pred action)
         (if (eq action 'metadata)
             '(metadata (display-sort-function . identity))
           (complete-with-action action items string pred))))
```

Comment: This looks fantastic! I'm not that experienced with emacs package management, I downloaded the .el files that were linked in the wiki and followed some instructions, but I icicles is not working. I'll work on it more when I get time. Should the icicles.el file start with <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ? I was right clicking links in the browser and saving them

Comment: No, it should not start with `<!DOCTYPE...`. You downloaded an HTML page. See [this page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries).

Comment: That's where I was, I right clicked the links and saved them. It looks like I need to click the link for each .el file and copy and paste from that webpage to make my local copy, is that right? I feel like I'm missing some download link

Comment: *Read [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries#BulkIciclesDownload).* You can use [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).

Comment: Thank you, sorry I missed that. I've got the files, but still haven't got it to load, I'm sure it is something I don't know about emacs package management, I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

An additional approach can be to define advice for `completion--insert-strings`. For instance, I wanted to

1. Sort symbols with `--` last.
2. Hide `*` buffers, unless explicitly filtering for them.

and came up with the following solution:

```
(advice-add #'completion--insert-strings :around #'my-cmplt-insstr)
(defun my-cmplt-insstr (oldfun strings &rest r)
  "Hook into `completion--insert-strings' that applies some postprocessing."

  ;; Symbols: Sort `--' after anything else.
  (when (cl-every #'intern-soft strings)
    (mylog "my-cmplt-insstr: -- comes last")
    (setq strings
          (cl-sort strings #'<
                   :key (lambda (it) (s-count-matches "--" it))))
    (setq strings
          (cl-loop with last-had-ddash = nil
                   for string in strings
                   for has-ddash = (string-match-p "--" string)
                   if (and has-ddash (not last-had-ddash))
                   collect ""
                   collect string
                   do (setq last-had-ddash has-ddash))))

  ;; Buffers: * hidden by default.
  (when (cl-member "*Messages*" strings :test #'string=)
    (unless (cl-every (lambda (it) (string-prefix-p "*" it)) strings)
      (setq strings
            (cl-remove-if (lambda (it) (string-prefix-p "*" it)) strings))))

  (apply oldfun strings r))
```

This solution uses rough heuristics to guess *what* is being completed, but it could be used as an alternate starting point, e.g. with specific `read-*` functions being advised to set flags for determining which rules are applied.